# Convert String to already declared object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have this code:

```
//Arguments are unique.

var Object1 = new Object(argument,argument,argument);

var Object2 = new Object(argument,argument,argument);

var Object3 = new Object(argument,argument,argument);

//...
var Object100 new Object(argument,argument,argument);


function convert(){
     var array = ["Object1","Object56"];
     // Manipulate values in array above as if they were the objects already
     //declared above this function, like acessing "Object56.argument" property.

}
```

I need to convert the the strings in the array to the objects that have already been declared, in order to manipulate the objects properties (which are converted from the arguments) in a function. I realize I'm basically turning JS objects into a database which is probably a bad idea but I was wondering if there's a solution to this? They way the values in the array are chosen is fairly complex and I think it would detract from the question, but they are randomly generated more or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing each object as a separate variable, create a map:

```
var objectMap = {
    Object1: new Object(argument, argument, argument),
    Object2: new Object(argument, argument, argument),
    // ...
    Object100: new Object(argument, argument, argument)
};
```

The mapping would then be easy enough.

You can either do it manually:

```
var array = ['Object1', 'Object2'];
var objects = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   var key = array[i];
   objects.push(objectMap[key]);
}
```

Or (if you're supporting ES5) use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) function:

```
var array = ['Object1', 'Object2'];
var objects = array.map(function (key) {
   return objectMap[key];
});
```